# Why are my JAR source files not consistently detected?

Tags: java, jar, ide

I need to use a library for my Java code, which comes in a handful (10 of them, to be exact) of .JAR files. No problem here.
The issue is trying to access these libraries' source code/files, so that my IDE can help me not f**k up anything.

See, the library actually *did* come with source files. One for each .JAR file.

The .JAR files are named in the format `<pathToPackage>-<version>.jar`, and the source files are named in the format `<pathToPackage>.source-<version>.jar`, with `<pathToPackage>` and `<version>` matching for every .JAR-source file duo.

However, for some unknown reason, ***only two (2) of them are successfully picked up by the IDE***.

I tried with VScode (with the Java Language Support extension), and IntelliJ, both giving the same result.

All of the source files are "proper" source files. I extracted their content in a separate folder, and am using that to navigate the source code.

Here are the files, for reference (grouped by which ones work, and which ones don't):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MISJ7vML7WI9BDzPXf7yGtrTWc7MgRjI/view

Comment: How do you tell your IDE about the jar and source files? Did you just drop them in a folder, or did you use the IDE import function? How will your IDE know what needs to be compiled and what needs to simply be packaged with the JAR?

Comment: Using a `.classpath` file.
`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="*path to the .JAR*"/>`